# NHibernate Mapping with No Id

Tags: nhibernate

Is it possible to do a mapping in NHibernate without using an Id?

What I'm trying to do is, call a stored procedure using

```
session.CreateSqlQuery( myQuery ).AddEntity( typeof( MyEntity ) );
```

The procedure is an aggregate and there is no Id field being returned, but I would still like to take advantage of NHibernate mapping the data returned into an entity. The only thing I have come up with so far is having the procedure add a field "O as Id" or something, and have the entity have a fake Id field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this really isn't possible. The data returned from the stored procedure has to have an Id also. It worked to just create a dummy column with an Id, and a dummy property on the object, but I just decided to convert the data returned by NHibernate to an object by hand.

Basically, you're not supposed to use stored procedures with NHibernate. It IS an ORM afterall. In my case, I had no choice but to use the procedure.

Answer (score 5):

Your entity must be "unique" in some way, even if it doesn't have an Id field.

Decide which properties, when taken together, must be unique, and use a composite key over them...

```
<composite-id>
  <key-property name="Property1" column="Column1"/>
  <key-property name="Property2" column="Column2"/>
</composite-id>
```

Answer (score 1):

From @Andy McCluggage's post:

You can very much do this in the mapping:

```
<composite-id>
  <key-property name="Property1" column="Column1"/>
  <key-property name="Property2" column="Column2"/>
</composite-id>
```

But, you must override Equals() and GetHashCode() in your model:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public virtual DateTime Property1;
    public virtual string Property2;
    public virtual int SomeOtherProperty;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(obj == null)
            return false;

        var t = obj as MyClass;

        if(t == null)
            return false;

        if (this.Property1 == t.Property1 && this.Property2 == t.Property2)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (this.Property1 + "|" + this.Property2).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to double-check the xsd, but I believe either id or composite-id are required. However, per the docs, name isn't required. So, you should be able to specify an almost-blank id section.

In a similar situation, I've set the class to mutable="false" and mapped the id to the row index and set the generator in the id mapping to assigned.

Comment: Okay - dumb question. How does one map to the row index? What does that look like in the mapping file? We looked for this in the documentation and decided to ask.